# How to fill in missing dates

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table as follows:

`create table users as(sent_at date, user_email varchar(128), score int, quota int);`

```
insert into users 
select '2022-01-18','user@email.com',50,200 
union
select '2022-01-15','user@email.com',34,400;
```

I'd like to get result set as:

```
select '2022-01-19','user@email.com',85,100 union
select '2022-01-18','user@email.com',50,200 union
select '2022-01-17','user@email.com',0,200 union        --Missing date with 0 score but quota from prior line
select '2022-01-16','user@email.com',0,200 union        --Missing date with 0 score but quota from prior line
select '2022-01-15','user@email.com',34,400;
```

I already have a table which has all the dates, e.g. schema.dates.
There are thousands of users in the table for which I need to fill in these gaps. I tried bunch of solutions but nothing is working.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query that would work. Start by cross joining all combinations of dates and users (add filters as needed), then left join the users table and calculate quota using the last_value() function (note that if you are using Snowflake, you must specify "rows between unbounded preceding and current row" as documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/last_value.html)):

```
with all_dates_users as (
--all combinations of dates and users
select date, user
from dates
cross join (select distinct user_email as user from users)
),
joined as (
--left join users table to the previous
select DU.date, DU.user, U.sent_at, U.user_email, U.score, U.quota
from all_dates_users DU
left join users U on U.sent_at = DU.date and U.user_email = DU.user
)
--calculate quota as previous quota using last_value() function
select date, user, nvl(score, 0) as score, last_value(quota) ignore nulls over (partition by user order by date desc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as quota
from joined
order by date desc;
```

Comment: This worked well. Thank you so so much. I was stuck there.

Answer (score 1):

Maja's solution using the WINDOW FUCNTION LAST_VALUE works well, Snowflake has another way to express that which is a little shorter [LAG IGNORE NULL OVER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lag.html) form.

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(day, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TRUE),'2022-01-01')::date AS date 
    FROM TABLE(generator(ROWCOUNT => 50))
), new_data AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
     ('2022-01-19','user@email.com',85,100),
     ('2022-01-18','user@email.com',50,200),
     ('2022-01-15','user@email.com',34,400)
    v(date, user_email, score , quota )
), users_ranges AS (
    SELECT 
        user_email, 
        min(date) as min_date, 
        max(date) as max_date
    FROM new_data
    GROUP BY 1
), dates_for_users AS (
    SELECT d.date,
        u.user_email
    FROM users_ranges AS u
    JOIN dates AS d 
        ON d.date between u.min_date and u.max_date    
)
SELECT du.date,
    du.user_email,
    ZEROIFNULL(u.score) as score,
    NVL(u.quota, LAG(u.quota) IGNORE NULLS OVER(partition by du.user_email order by du.date)) as quota
FROM dates_for_users AS du
LEFT JOIN new_data AS u
    ON du.date = u.date AND du.user_email = u.user_email
ORDER BY 1 desc,2;
```

Which gives:

| DATE | USER_EMAIL | SCORE | QUOTA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-19 | user@email.com | 85 | 100 |
| 2022-01-18 | user@email.com | 50 | 200 |
| 2022-01-17 | user@email.com | 0 | 400 |
| 2022-01-16 | user@email.com | 0 | 400 |
| 2022-01-15 | user@email.com | 34 | 400 |

As your problem is described, there is a tiny logic gap of you onyl give two rows, but are expecting a large date range, but I assume that is not the heart of the problem, and you just really want the LAG / LAST_VALUE logic.

This works by `dates` & `new_data` are just the table proxies. Then `users_ranges` is used to find the time ranges for each user, that will be used for the join dates the `dates` table which happens in `dates_for_users`. Now we have all the date gaps filled for each user, we can left join to the new data, to get score and [zero if null](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/zeroifnull.html), and use LAG to get the prior QUOTA ignoring nulls, which a little [NVL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nvl.html) to only use the LAG value if the current row does not have a value (COALESCE can also be used for this).

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt. It does work if one user is added; I would need sample data for several users, with `sent_at` dates on different days to see if it works with many users.

```
WITH
-- your users table after inserting the two rows you insert, 
-- and with a previous row dated '2022-01-19' - don't use in query
users(sent_at,user_email,score,quota) AS (
            SELECT DATE '2022-01-19','user@email.com',85,100
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-18','user@email.com',50,200
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-15','user@email.com',34,400
)
,
-- a cutout of the calendar table you mentioned - don't use in query either
calendar(dt) AS (
            SELECT DATE '2022-01-14'
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-15'
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-16'
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-17'
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-18'
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-19'
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-20'
)
-- real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH" ...
,
-- can be done differently, but I like determining filters early ..
limits AS (
  SELECT
    MIN(sent_at) AS mindt
  , MAX(sent_at) AS maxdt
  FROM users
)
,
-- fill the time gaps with a left join from calendar to users table
gaps_filled AS (
  SELECT
    dt AS sent_at
  , user_email
  , NVL(score,0) AS score
  , quota
  FROM calendar
  LEFT JOIN users ON calendar.dt=users.sent_at
)
-- use LAST_VALUE( .. IGNORE NULLS) to fill the NULL gaps from earlier rows
-- CROSS JOIN with the in-line limits table to get the filter dates
SELECT
  sent_at
, LAST_VALUE(gaps_filled.user_email IGNORE NULLS) 
     OVER(ORDER BY sent_at DESC) AS user_email 
, NVL(score,0)  AS score
, LAST_VALUE(quota IGNORE NULLS) 
     OVER(ORDER BY sent_at DESC) AS quota 
FROM gaps_filled
CROSS JOIN limits
WHERE sent_at BETWEEN mindt AND maxdt
ORDER BY user_email, sent_at DESC;
-- out Null display is "(null)".
-- out   sent_at   |   user_email   | score | quota 
-- out ------------+----------------+-------+-------
-- out  2022-01-19 | user@email.com |    85 |   100
-- out  2022-01-18 | user@email.com |    50 |   200
-- out  2022-01-17 | user@email.com |     0 |   200
-- out  2022-01-16 | user@email.com |     0 |   200
-- out  2022-01-15 | user@email.com |    34 |   400
```