# Snowflake / Snowpark fill gaps in between date ranges with current value

Tags: sql, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this query in Snowflake:

```
WITH min_max_date AS (
SELECT
    min(sales_date) AS min_date,
    max(sales_date) AS max_date
FROM sales),
generated_dates AS (
    SELECT
        last_day(dateadd('month', row_number() over (ORDER BY seq4())-1, min_date)) as _monthend
    FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 100000))
    CROSS JOIN min_max_date QUALIFY _monthend <= max_date
)
select
g._monthend as monthend,
h.id,
h.new_ind
from generated_dates g
left join public.customer h on g._monthend = last_day(h.change_date)
order by _monthend;
```

Which returns

| monthend_date | id | new_ind |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-09-30 | 123 | 1 |
| 2011-03-31 | 123 | 2 |
| 2012-07-31 | 123 | 3 |

I would like to fill in the gaps between monthend_dates with all the generated _monthend, and assign with `new_ind` until it changes.

So the output should look like:

| monthend_date | id | new_ind |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-09-30 | 123 | 1 |
| 2010-10-31 | 123 | 1 |
| 2010-11-30 | 123 | 1 |
| 2010-12-31 | 123 | 1 |
| 2011-01-31 | 123 | 1 |
| 2011-02-31 | 123 | 1 |
| 2011-03-31 | 123 | 2 |

I tried using a coalesce and lag function, but it didnt work out:

Update: using the query as suggested by the comments, this still returns NULL on the _monthend values, except when there is a direct match on a single _monthend value.

```
WITH min_max_date AS (
SELECT
    min(sales_date) AS min_date,
    max(sales_date) AS max_date
FROM sales),
generated_dates AS (
    SELECT
        last_day(dateadd('month', row_number() over (ORDER BY null), min_date)) as _monthend
    FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 100000))
    CROSS JOIN min_max_date QUALIFY _monthend <= max_date
),
ind_history AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        new_ind,
        sales_date
    FROM public.customer
)
SELECT
    g._monthend AS monthend,
    COALESCE(s.new_ind,
              lag(s.new_ind) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY sales_date)) AS new_ind
FROM public.customer s
LEFT JOIN ind_history s ON g._monthend = last_day(s.sales_date)
ORDER BY _monthend;
```

I would actually like to do have it as a Pyspark / Snowflake code, so not sure if that is easier to do

Comment: how about LAST_VALUE window function, IGNORE NULLS

Comment: use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY null)` instead of any of the `SEQx()` functions, as the doc's note, they can (and thus do) have gaps.

Comment: @josh this does not work, it just returns the max(new_ind) and fills for all records

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim could you please expand on that? I do not understand

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70812500/how-to-fill-in-missing-dates/70817639#70817639

Comment: Should we close this question as a duplicate of @SimeonPilgrim link up there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fill in missing dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70812500/how-to-fill-in-missing-dates)

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim unfortunately not, I tried to adapt the answers from that question, but it is not working for me. I cannot fill in the gaps.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim I have updated my original question with the suggestions, but the updated query does not work

Comment: I'll be happy to tack this question @Dametime - can you help me generate the data so I can reproduce?

Answer (score 2):

so creating some fake data to show the steps:

```
WITH fake_sales_data as (
    select 
        try_to_date(column1, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as sales_date 
    from values
        ('2010-09-30'),
        ('2011-03-31'),
        ('2012-07-31') 
), fake_customer(change_date, id, new_ind) as (
    select 
        try_to_date(column1, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), column2, column3 
    from values
        ('2010-09-21', 0, 1 ),
        ('2011-03-14', 1, 2 ),
        ('2011-06-15', 2, 3 )
)
```

we can then apply your code to this:

```
WITH fake_sales_data as (
    select 
        try_to_date(column1, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as sales_date 
    from values
        ('2010-09-30'),
        ('2011-03-31'),
        ('2012-07-31') 
), fake_customer(change_date, id, new_ind) as (
    select 
        try_to_date(column1, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), column2, column3 
    from values
        ('2010-09-21', 0, 1 ),
        ('2011-03-14', 1, 2 ),
        ('2011-06-15', 2, 3 )
), min_max_date AS (
    SELECT
        min(sales_date) AS min_date,
        max(sales_date) AS max_date
    FROM fake_sales_data
), generated_dates AS (
    SELECT
        last_day(dateadd('month', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TRUE)-1, min_date)) as _monthend
    FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 100000))
    CROSS JOIN min_max_date 
    QUALIFY _monthend <= max_date
)
select
g._monthend as monthend,
h.id,
h.new_ind
from generated_dates as g
left join fake_customer as h 
    on g._monthend = last_day(h.change_date)
order by _monthend;
```

and get the dates, yippie, but gaps:

| MONTHEND | ID | NEW_IND |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-09-30 | 0 | 1 |
| 2010-10-31 | null | null |
| 2010-11-30 | null | null |
| 2010-12-31 | null | null |
| 2011-01-31 | null | null |
| 2011-02-28 | null | null |
| 2011-03-31 | 1 | 2 |
| 2011-04-30 | null | null |
| 2011-05-31 | null | null |
| 2011-06-30 | 2 | 3 |
| 2011-07-31 | null | null |
| 2011-08-31 | null | null |
| 2011-09-30 | null | null |
| 2011-10-31 | null | null |
| 2011-11-30 | null | null |
| 2011-12-31 | null | null |
| 2012-01-31 | null | null |
| 2012-02-29 | null | null |
| 2012-03-31 | null | null |
| 2012-04-30 | null | null |
| 2012-05-31 | null | null |
| 2012-06-30 | null | null |
| 2012-07-31 | null | null |

now we want to fill in the prior `newid`'s with the before mentioned LAG

just showing the last select here:

```
select
g._monthend as monthend,
h.id,
NVL(h.new_ind, LAG(h.new_ind)ignore nulls over(order by g._monthend)) as new_ind
from generated_dates as g
left join fake_customer as h 
    on g._monthend = last_day(h.change_date)
order by _monthend;
```

gives:

| MONTHEND | ID | NEW_IND |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-09-30 | 0 | 1 |
| 2010-10-31 | null | 1 |
| 2010-11-30 | null | 1 |
| 2010-12-31 | null | 1 |
| 2011-01-31 | null | 1 |
| 2011-02-28 | null | 1 |
| 2011-03-31 | 1 | 2 |
| 2011-04-30 | null | 2 |
| 2011-05-31 | null | 2 |
| 2011-06-30 | 2 | 3 |
| 2011-07-31 | null | 3 |
| 2011-08-31 | null | 3 |
| 2011-09-30 | null | 3 |
| 2011-10-31 | null | 3 |
| 2011-11-30 | null | 3 |
| 2011-12-31 | null | 3 |
| 2012-01-31 | null | 3 |
| 2012-02-29 | null | 3 |
| 2012-03-31 | null | 3 |
| 2012-04-30 | null | 3 |
| 2012-05-31 | null | 3 |
| 2012-06-30 | null | 3 |
| 2012-07-31 | null | 3 |

Comment: Thank you! I would like to ask, why do you not use "partition by h.id " in the LAG window?

Comment: this is strange. I tried it with the real data and using your exact query, it does not work.

But if I add an extra condition to the left join, I can see the results. Like "and h.id=165". Why does this happen? It does not work when all the IDs are selected.

Edit: I added an extra row to your fake date: "('2010-03-14', 1, 1 ),". It seems that if two IDs have dates that overlap, it will not work

Comment: I cant edit the above, but i made a typo. I inserted this to the fake date: 

"('2010-11-14', 1, 1 ),". Now the values for ID =0 are lost, and are overwritten by ID=1

Comment: Ah. Yes. So the data should be paritioned by the id, but you example was too trivial, but it makes sense you only want the last id per id. Will update the answer soon

Comment: you have 3 problems, "how you blend you data together", which is seems you have not solved yourself, how to date range across that data, how to lag across that data. This answer show how to do the latter two steps. its seems you now have found your problem is more complex than you described, and as such the simple example of how to do what you ask, does not work. If you can solve for yourself the first point, then this answer does show how to solve your latter points, albeit not how to partition the lag.